# Problema con Recyclerview y el teclado

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estoy haciendo un especie de red social con Firestore y actualmente estoy implementando en un Fragment la funcionalidad de buscar usuarios que se encuentren registrados en firebase, el usuario escribe el nombre en un EditText, hace click en el botón de "buscar" y la aplicación busca los usuarios cuyo username contenga esos caracteres para luego mostrarlos en un RecyclerView debajo del EditText.

El problema es que cuando hago click en buscar no muestra los resultados instantáneamente en la pantalla si no que tengo que manualmente (con una función hidekeyboard() que hice tampoco funciona) ocultar el teclado para que aparezcan en el RecyclerView.

**Esto es lo que pasa:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esto es lo que debería pasar:**

[image: Esto es lo que debería pasar]

**Fragment:**

```
class SearchFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_search) {
private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
private var dbsearchitems= mutableListOf<Profile>()
private val storage = Firebase.storage
private lateinit var root: View

private var recycler: RecyclerView?=null
private var itemadapter: SearchItemAdapter?=null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)!!

    setup(root)
    return root
}

private fun setup(root: View){

    root.findViewById<Button>(R.id.SearchBtn).setOnClickListener{
        dbsearchitems.clear()
        val text = root.searchField.text.toString()
        if(text != ""){
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user").get().addOnSuccessListener{ result ->
                    for(doc in result){
                        doc.reference.collection("Data").get().addOnSuccessListener {res2 ->
                                for(doc2 in res2){
                                    val item = doc2.toObject(Profile::class.java)
                                    if(item.alias.indexOf(text) != -1){
                                        dbsearchitems.add(item)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            //hideKeyboard()
            pintarRes()
        }
    }
}

private fun pintarRes(){
    recycler = root.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.searchRes)
    recycler?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    itemadapter = context?.let { SearchItemAdapter(it,dbsearchitems) }
    recycler?.adapter = itemadapter
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/borderitem">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lupa"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchField"
                android:layout_width="224dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/lupa"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="Username, Alias.." />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/SearchBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/searchField"
                android:text="Buscar" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/searchRes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    tools:listitem="@layout/view_searchitem" />
```

**Adapter:**

```
class SearchItemAdapter(var context:Context, var listItems: List<Profile>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchItemAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    var username = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.searchItemUsername)
    var alias = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.searchItemAlias)
    var addBtn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.searchItemAddBtn)
    var pfp = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.searchitemPfp)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_searchitem, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SearchItemAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = listItems[position]
    holder.username.text = item.username
    holder.alias.text = item.alias
    //Glide.with(holder.view).load(item.avatarURL.toUri()).into(holder.pfp)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return listItems.size
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}
```

Ya es que no se cuando videos y post he visto sobre temas o problemas con RecyclerViews y no se que mas probar, cual podría ser la solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que esperas que los resultados de firestore sean instantáneos cuando en realidad no lo son. En tu clickListener haces algo como esto

```
root.findViewById<Button>(R.id.SearchBtn).setOnClickListener {
    ...
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user").get().addOnSuccessListener {
        // almacena los resultados en dbsearchitems
        ...
    }
    // lee los items de dbsearchitems
    pintarRes()
}
```

Pero no tienes en cuenta que todo el código dentro del `OnSuccessListener` no se ejecutará hasta que se haya completado la consulta, lo cual siempre ocurrirá **después** de llamar a `pintarRes()`. Es decir que el recyclerView no muestra los resultados porque la lista de resultados (`dbsearchitems`) está vacía.

Luego al cerrar el teclado, el layout se refresca y entonces aparecen los resultados. Con tu función `hideKeyboard` no funcionó porque también la colocaste fuera del `OnSuccessListener` y entonces el teclado se cerraba cuando la lista todavía estaba vacía.

Para solucionarlo simplemente debes llamar `pintarRes()` después que los resultados se hayan cargado en la lista

```
root.findViewById<Button>(R.id.SearchBtn).setOnClickListener {
    ...
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user").get().addOnSuccessListener {
        ...
        pintarRes()
    }
}
```

Comment: vale, ya entiendo el problema, si, cambie eso en el código y ya funciona como tenia pensado, muchas gracias!